# How to ignore class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is simple example I did:
http://jsfiddle.net/J3rBX/

My purpose: when I mouseover that input, it would give me an alert. Everything seems fine, but when I mouseover that text which has class 'txt', it doesn't give me an alert. What should I do?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but what you're attempting is a plausible but hopeless solution to several similar sorts of things I've seen.

Comment: $(".omg, .txt").bind("mouseover", function() { ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.txt` to the selector:

```
$(".omg, .txt").bind("mouseover", function() {
       alert("i mouseover'ed omg class");
})
```

Setting `pointer-events: none;` on the `.txt` class also works.

Comment: pointer-events: none; - that what I was looking for :) Does all browsers support that?

Comment: no, Lynx dosn't support it ;-) At least the five major browser support it.

Comment: @Saxoier: Nice humour, but seriously, is it ok? :)

Comment: I think IE doesn't support it.

Comment: MSIE/JScript has support for it. IE (JScript) through [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari (JavaScript) through [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Comment: It's only supported in IE as of IE9. I think the first approach is better - just add `.txt` to the selector.

Comment: `pointer-events` is still too new, there are a lot of older browsers out there that do not support it yet, mainly the older (and not so old) IE versions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `<span>` appears *after* the `<input>`, so it's "on top" of the `<input>` and it effectively blocks the mouse events.